# Flutter cannot send instance of a class to a widget

Tags: flutter, firebase

i have some future functions that fetch some data from firebase, puts them in a class and returns the class. I created three variables that store the function call and get all of them using Future.wait. Once I get all three classes I have to put them in a page, when I call the page. Here is the code snippet:

```
          Future<Class1> class1data =
          FirestoreService().getClass1(pathComponents[1]);
      Future<List<Class2>> class2data =
          FirestoreService().getListClass2(pathComponents[1]);
      Future<List<Class3>> class3data =
          FirestoreService().getListClass3(pathComponents[1]);

      Future.wait([class1data, class2data, class3data]).then(
        (value) {
          
      
              return MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) {
                return MainPage(
                    class1: value[0],
                    class2: value[1]!,
                    class3: value[2]!,
          );
              },
              maintainState: false);
        },
      );
```

From this code, I cannot call the MaterialPageRoute with the main page because of the parameters. If I hover over class1: value[0] I get this: `The argument type 'Object' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'class1'` and if I print value[0] I get instance of class1. Why Is this and why doesn't it allow me to pass value[0], value[1] and value[2] to the page?

Constructor of main page:

```
  final Class1 class1;
  final List<Class2> class2;
  final List<Class3> class3;
    const MainPage(
      {super.key,
      required this.class1,
      required this.class2,
      required this.class3});
```

Comment: Can you share the constructor of `MainPage`? It seems that it has a different type from what you try to pass to it.

Comment: So the value returned from `FirestoreService().getClass1` is not type of `Class1`. You need to convert or cast it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this:

```dart
(context) {
                return MainPage(
                    class1: value[0] as Class1,
                    class2: value[1]! as List<Class2>,
                    class3: value[2]! as List<Class3>,
          );
              },
```